# How to refer two different meta models (like autosar422 and 446)in one project

Tags: eclipse, emf, autosar

In my eclipse project I am trying to access two different autosar meta models(autosar446 and autosar422), but the meta model descriptor id for both version is same, so how can I use both within the same project (I observed that since the id is same emf.sphinx is unable to differentiate the model).

Comment: Are those EMF metamodels ? Do they have the same URI ?

Comment: Yeah, those are sphinx emf meta models and NS URI is same for both.

Comment: I assume, you use artop? It usually takes the latest available. In a project, you can narrow it down to a specific subrelease (see Project Setiings), but it means for all files. That usually has the effect, the the models are up- or down-converted, and for down-conversion could mean the loss of certain AUTOSAR MetaModel elements replaced by SDGs (because the elements are not available in the old one).